# URI must be ascii only when Spreadsheet open file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to read excel file, I use follow code to open excel:

```
file = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file_path)
```

But when `file_path` contain japanese,error occur:

```
URI::InvalidURIError: URI must be ascii only "/Users/myname/Project/Test/tmp/data/\u{611b}\u{77e5}\u{770c}/s000226.xlsx"
```

I tried URI to parse `file_path` but not work. 
How to fix it? Thanks you.

Comment: `file = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(URI.enconde(file_path))`. Does it work?

Comment: @lcguida: I tried it, but not work.

Comment: There seem to be a problem with your file_path variable. `\u{611b}\u{77e5}\u{770c}` is definitely not good. If you have a problem, it's coming from that variable/how you set it.

Comment: I tried with the newest version (v2.3.1) of `roo` and it can open such path that contains `愛知県`. BTW, I tested it on my Ubuntu Linux, and I don't have a MAC.

Comment: @Aetherus: I using version 2.3.0, but not work.

Comment: @dieuhd Which OS do you work on? Windows? If so, windows uses old UTF-16LE with BOM to represent unicode characters, but ruby uses UTF-8 since 1.9, and before that, iso-8859-1.

Comment: @Aetherus: I am using MacOS. I tried convert encoding but not work :(

Comment: @dieuhd What's you ruby version?

Comment: @Aetherus: Ruby version 2.2.3 , I try use ruby version 2.3.0 but not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
File.open(path, 'rb') do |file|
  xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file, extension: '.xlsx')
end
```